# MySQL: Calculate value and set when triggered by an INSERT in another table

Tags: mysql

Quick intro: I am trying to make a program that would allow me and my friends to keep track of who ows who money. Right now I am working on the database.
I am testing it on [this website.](https://paiza.io/projects/gmMbC36xAZmPG0bpcuoZiQ?language=mysql)

```
CREATE TABLE `payments`
(
 `payment_id` integer NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
 `title`      varchar(200) NOT NULL ,
 `descrp`     tinytext NULL ,
 `room_id`    integer NOT NULL ,
 `u_from`       integer NOT NULL ,
 `u_to`         integer NOT NULL ,
 `value`      decimal DEFAULT 0, CHECK (value>=0),

PRIMARY KEY (`payment_id`),
KEY `fkIdx_39` (`u_from`),
CONSTRAINT `FK_38` FOREIGN KEY `fkIdx_39` (`u_from`) REFERENCES `users` (`user_id`),
KEY `fkIdx_42` (`u_to`),
CONSTRAINT `FK_41` FOREIGN KEY `fkIdx_42` (`u_to`) REFERENCES `users` (`user_id`),
KEY `fkIdx_51` (`room_id`),
CONSTRAINT `FK_50` FOREIGN KEY `fkIdx_51` (`room_id`) REFERENCES `rooms` (`room_id`)
);


CREATE TABLE `rooms`
(
 `room_id`  integer NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
 `web_link` varchar(30) NOT NULL ,
 `name`     varchar(200) NOT NULL ,
 `descrp`   tinytext,

PRIMARY KEY (`room_id`)
);


CREATE TABLE `user_room`
(
 `id`        integer NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
 `user_id`   integer NOT NULL ,
 `room_id`   integer NOT NULL ,
 `user_role` varchar(200) DEFAULT "standard" ,
 `cash`      decimal NOT NULL DEFAULT 0 ,

PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
KEY `fkIdx_16` (`user_id`),
CONSTRAINT `FK_15` FOREIGN KEY `fkIdx_16` (`user_id`) REFERENCES `users` (`user_id`),
KEY `fkIdx_36` (`room_id`),
CONSTRAINT `FK_35` FOREIGN KEY `fkIdx_36` (`room_id`) REFERENCES `rooms` (`room_id`)
);


CREATE TABLE `users`
(
 `user_id`      integer NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
 `login`        varchar(50) NOT NULL ,
 `display_name` varchar(100) NULL ,

PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`)
);


DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER after_new_payment_sum_cash
AFTER INSERT ON payments FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    DECLARE user_from_cash decimal;
    DECLARE user_to_cash   decimal;
    SET @user_from_cash := (SELECT cash FROM user_room WHERE user_id = NEW.u_from);
    SET @user_to_cash   := (SELECT cash FROM user_room WHERE user_id = NEW.u_to);

    UPDATE user_room SET cash = (user_from_cash - NEW.value) WHERE user_id = NEW.u_from;
    UPDATE user_room SET cash = (user_to_cash + NEW.value) WHERE user_id = NEW.u_to;

END //
DELIMITER ;


INSERT INTO users     (login, display_name)    VALUES ("kacper1", "Kacper2");
INSERT INTO users     (login, display_name)    VALUES ("kacper2", "Kacper2");
INSERT INTO rooms     (web_link, name, descrp) VALUES ('xx', 'room1', 'description');
INSERT INTO user_room (user_id, room_id)       VALUES ((SELECT user_id FROM users WHERE login='kacper1'),
                                                             (SELECT room_id FROM rooms WHERE name ='room1'));
INSERT INTO user_room (user_id, room_id)       VALUES ((SELECT user_id FROM users WHERE login='kacper2'),
                                                             (SELECT room_id FROM rooms WHERE name ='room1'));

select * from users;
select * from rooms;
select * from user_room;
select * from payments;

INSERT INTO payments (title, descrp, room_id, u_from, u_to, value) VALUES ('plat1', 'plat1 desc', 1, 1, 2, 10);

select * from user_room;
```

As you can see by yourself I get this error: `ERROR 1048 (23000) at line 88: Column 'cash' cannot be null`
The purpose of the trigger is to calculate the `cash` filed in `user_room` table for `user_from` and `user_to` and keep it constantly updated.
As far as I understand this, one of the `SET...` lines is giving this error.

Comment: MySQL <> SQL Server. Tag correctly.

Comment: Delete sql tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The formula `user_from_cash - NEW.value` becomes `NULL` as it should be `@user_from_cash`.

Further improvement:

1. You better use local variables inside the trigger (not @var)
2. `DECIMAL`-datatype should have length defined.